Color coding Infor XA with mathematical functions?
Is it possible in Infor XA (GUI, power link?) to use mathematical functions when color coding?
I want to color "Stock" red when stock is lower then "Quantity used latest 12 months" / 4 but can't find a way to do so. I want to have it in steps of 6 months, 3 months and 1 month.
I tried going into the color coding where I can tell it to color code  red if it is less then  but I can't specify or add math.
